# Ignoring a directory using ack's .ackrc

Tags: ack

I'm not sure what it's for, but the code I'm working on has a bunch of folders called "save.d," it looks like they're used for some sort of version control (we also have .svn folders).

How can I update my .ackrc file to ignore those directories by default?

My .ackrc is currently

```
--type-set=inc=.inc
--ignore-dir=pear
--type-set=tpl=.tpl
```

Our folder structure can look like:

```
program/parsers/save.d
program/modules/save.d
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Adding another line `--ignore-dir=save.d` did the trick

Comment: Also note that you can add that to the command line whenever necessary, or ACK_OPTIONS environment variable.  Your ackrc is nothing but command line switches.