# ACK: Exclude specific paths (a dir and its subdirs) from search

Tags: regex, shell, grep, ack

With [ACK 2.x](http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.0/), I can specify command line options to exclude certain dirs from showing up in results. For example, to exclude the directory 'test' [I can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917572/139040):

`ack -v -g 'test' | ack -x pattern`
*('test' can be a regex for dirs to exclude)*

I can also [ignore a directory using .ackrc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502935/139040), by adding `--ignore-dir=save.d` to .ackrc or using it as a command line option. But it seems that I cannot exclude paths (a dir and its subdirs) using RegEx. I tried adding the following:

`--ignore-dir=match:^\/specific\/path\/to\/test\/.*$`

and also the following variations

`--ignore-dir=match:/^\/specific\/path\/to\/test\/.*$/`

`--ignore-dir=match:\/specific\/path\/to\/test\/.*`

`--ignore-dir=match:/specific/path/to/test/.*`

`--ignore-dir=match:/specific/path/to/test/`

(according to this user, [--ignore-dir and --ignore-file and indeed all file-match in ack is done with regular expressions, *not* with shell glob patterns](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ack-users/755NSHRWPdQ/s8WDvyOyPs0J), but I also tried using shell glob patterns.)

but this gives me:

`Non-is filters are not yet supported for --ignore-dir at /usr/bin/ack line 157`

*Taking out the 'match:' part from the alternatives above does not produce an error, but doesn't exclude the dirs either.*

The [manual](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.12-man.html#no_ignore_dir_dirname_no_ignore_directory_dirname) states that "nested directories like foo/bar are NOT supported". To settle this, **on ACK at least up to ACK 2.12 it is impossible to exclude specific dirs and subdirectories. It's only possible to exclude all paths of which a dir matches a simple string or a regex. Or is there an undocumented clever way around this limitation?**

Comment: By the way, it's one annoying limitation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported, I'm affraid. See

[--ignore-dir doesn't support absolute pathnames · Issue #291 · petdance/ack2](https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/291)

I came to this post for something similar and found the above issue... :-(